# launch job from within a job so that parent job should not wait for child to complete in spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-batch-admin

I want to launch different jobs from my main batch job. Currently I am using job step e.g.

```
<job id="importJob">
    <step id="import.importPricesAndQuoteListStep">
        <job ref="importPricesAndQuoteListJob" />
    </step> 
     .....  
     ...... 
</job>
```

It launches the child job importPricesAndQuoteListJob and waits for it to complete. I dont want to wait for this step to complete. Instead, I just want to launch this job and move ahead to other steps.

May be spring batch integration JobLaunchingMessageHandler can help but I am not sure how to build job launch request from parent job for child job ?

Is there any adapter for this which converts the above step to job launch request ? Is there any example ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that this isn't possible out of the box.  A `JobStep` is a step just like any other.  Because of that, it needs to complete before the next step is executed.

That being said, if you have a finite list of jobs you want to run in parallel, you can use a `split` to run steps in parallel.  This would allow those jobs to run in parallel.

Beyond that, what is the relation between the jobs?  That relationship may direct a better solution for orchestrating the child jobs.